# Getting started with SSL

Tags: ssl

After reading articles about SSL online (a while ago, sources forgotten) - I've come to the conclusion that half of SSL related articles are full of . While the other half seem to suggest that SSL is a must if you're selling stuff on your site.

My question is, after trying to find this out on Google, is How do you actually use SSL, like how do you put it on your site?

I'm not sure why, but I was always under the impression that to make SSL work with your website you just pay for an SSL Certificate and just enter your website's details on your SSL providers site and it just get sets up somehow by the SSL service?

Is there any programming involved?

Comment: What server do you use? Using SSL mainly consists of configuring your server.

Comment: I use Winhost.com - they resell SSL Cert's. But, I don't plan on using them. I plan on signing up test/playground account with a hosting provider that DOESN'T sell/resell them, so I can set it up myself - just to learn how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find a hosting provider, that provides root access.
2. Install openSSL
3. Install web server
4. Follow instructions to generate certificate signing request PKCS#12 (from memory) for web server
5. Have request signed by verisign or other trusted authority. $$$
6. Install signed cert into web server

Good to go. Instructions are from memory, 3am in the morning. Mostly right, but no programming required. Detailed instructions should be available from your hosting provider. Follow them.

You could skip step 5 and install your own Certificate Authority, but then your users will get alert messages when they try and establish a secure connection with your site. Bad UX if you actually want to sell something or establish secure connection with standard browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the instructions! Much appreciated, @Jordan :)

Comment: Probably you can skip the first few steps by finding a provider that officially _supports_ SSL, they might help you set it up without any programming.

Answer (score 1):

SSL can work without involving any Certification Authority. So CA are not mandatory. 
Of course if you don't use CA your user needs a way to get your certificate off-line (to be sure that no MiTM will be performed on your first connection to the your site).
Otherwise the user can accept the certificate sent back by your web server on the first connection (but this is susceptible to MiTM on the first connection ).

Also, CA doesn't do anything except giving a third-part trust upon your certificate, all implementations issues are up to you.